# php how to read csv fields as text instead of numbers

Tags: php, csv, text

I have a csv file which I wrote a php program to convert to a JSON format. I would like to treat all the CSV fields as text and not as numbers so it can be sorted in a proper order. a Snippet of the CSV file....

```
Sect,Villa#,VillaName,VillaAlbum,
Royal,01,,https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=oa.414280856573153&type=3, 
Royal,09,,https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=oa.226012065672791&type=3,
Royal,10,,https://www.facebook.com/media/set?set=oa.1565194250343401&type=3,
Royal,11,,https://www.facebook.com/media/set?set=oa.1077929672691549&type=3,
```

which I read and convert to a JSON file using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>Convert CSV to JSON for use in LHVCResortMap site</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="Don Simard simard57@hotmail.com CC0260">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.png">

  <!-- sorttable.js is borrowed from https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ -->
  <script src="/scripts/sorttable.js"> </script> 
  <script> 
    $promptString = "JSON string to paste into file";
    prompt($promptString, $str);
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/LHVC.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/navbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sorttable.css">

  <body>
    <h1> Convert the "Villa Site List.csv" to .json</h1>
    <h2> Working directory is "Log/Utils" </h2>
    <h3> remember to move the "Log/Utils/Villa Site List.json" file to the root directory </h3>
    
    <?php
    
      include_once "manifest.php"; // manifest of files used by LHVC website utilities 

      if (file_exists($WorkingVillaCSVfile)) {
        echo "$WorkingVillaCSVfile found<br>";
      }
      else {
        echo "$WorkingVillaCSVfile not found<br>";
      }

      if (file_exists($WorkingVillaJSONfile)) {
        echo "$WorkingVillaJSONfile found<br>";
        echo "Removing file<br>";
        unlink($WorkingVillaJSONfile);
      }
      else {
        echo "$WorkingVillaJSONfile not found<br>";
      }

      $csv = file_get_contents($WorkingVillaCSVfile);
      $lines = explode("\n", $csv);

      //remove the first element from the array
      $head = str_getcsv(array_shift($lines));

      $data = array();
      $count=0;
      foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if ($line) {
          $data[] = array_combine($head, str_getcsv($line));
          $count += 1;
        }
      }
      $JSONfile = Array();
      $JSONfile ["Fields"] = $head;

      $i=0;
      $body = array();
      foreach($data as $item) {
        if ($item) {
          $sect=array_shift($item);
          $body[$sect][] = $item;
        }
        asort($body[$sect]);
      }
      $JSONfile["Villas"]=$body;
      $json=json_encode ($JSONfile,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      
      $bytes = file_put_contents($WorkingVillaJSONfile, $json);

      echo "<br> <br>converted $count entries.<br> total $bytes bytes."
    ?>
  </body>
</html>.
```

The problem I am having is that the JSON file that is written is removing the leading 0 in the Villa# field which means it will not sort as I want to. Is there something I can do to treat all the fields as text ?

```
{
    "Fields": [
        "Sect",
        "Villa#",
        "VillaName",
        "VillaAlbum",
        "Owner",
        "OwnerSite",
        "BRs",
        "StreetMBR",
        "StreetBR",
        "UpperMBR",
        "UpperBR",
        "LowerMBR",
        "LowerBR",
        "Comments"
    ],
    "Villas": {
        "Royal": [
            {
                "Villa#": "1",
                "VillaName": "",
                "VillaAlbum": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/media\/set\/?set=oa.414280856573153&type=3",
                "Owner": "",
                "OwnerSite": "",
                "BRs": "3",
                "StreetMBR": "1",
                "StreetBR": "0",
                "UpperMBR": "0",
                "UpperBR": "2",
                "LowerMBR": "",
                "LowerBR": "",
                "Comments": "Very nice. Highly recommended. Upstairs Theatre Seating"
            },
            {
                "Villa#": "2",
                "VillaName": "",
                "VillaAlbum": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/media\/set\/?set=oa.418121152942195&type=3",
                "Owner": "",
                "OwnerSite": "",
                "BRs": "4",
                "StreetMBR": "1",
                "StreetBR": "",
                "UpperMBR": "",
                "UpperBR": "3",
                "LowerMBR": "",
                "LowerBR": "",
                "Comments": "Newly built - beautiful!"
            },
```

Comment: Using the snippet of the file I get `"Villa#": "01",`

Comment: WFM: https://3v4l.org/RTBnZ

Comment: odd! I posted the output I saw, I wonder why they are different

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
$data[] = array_combine($head, str_getcsv($line));
```

to

```
$data[] = array_combine($head, explode(',',$line));
```

and got what I was looking for.

Comment: might need to watch out for `,` inside comments etc, if your trying to force `01` to be `01` and not `1` then use `str_pad` https://3v4l.org/V2I3S or `sprintf` https://3v4l.org/5Kla3

Comment: the downside of CSV. unsure what Excel does with comma when saving as a csv

I just tested what Excel does with a cell that has commas and see it quotes

Comment: I just tested what Excel does with a cell that has commas and see it quotes the strings with comments. Now what can I do on the input side to counter that?

fortunately, I have replaced the csv with a JSON version and maintain the CSV as a means to share outside the site I am using... I suppose I will have to look at writing a reverse program (JSON2CSV)